# C++ Stream class failed to open the file

Tags: c++, file

I write small test application in C++ to read the file data, So when I used the C++ -Stream class to read from files, it fails to open the file stream for the file name which gets passed as argument of the Stream class object.

Also I keep my file(Test.txt) in the directory where my program executable is kept and run.

```
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ifstream testFile("Test.txt");

    string line;
    if (testFile.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(testFile, line))
        {
            line += line;
        }
    }


}
```

please also find the additional debug capture which has been captured from visual studio debugger.
[image]

Comment: That screenshot seems to be from Visual Studio, is that correct? Then you should know that the working directory of your program when running might not be what you expect it to be. You might want to explicitly set it to a specific path just to be safe.

Comment: This question again? There must be dozens of duplicates somewhere.

Comment: @Some programmer dude, Thanks for your reply. But As I intend to extend this program for Linux, I decided to keep the Test.txt file in the directory where the exe is kept. Also when it is fully functional , I will pass the fileName as cmd argument of the main function. So I can not give the full path as it may vary in the future.

Comment: Then go into your projects settings to set the working directory when running or debugging, and change the directory to where the file is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run a program from the editor/IDE it is not always true (and generally it isn't) that the root directory for relative paths is the project directory or the one where the .exe is placed. If you run the executable from the command line placed in the directory it should work, but if you run it when the command line isn't in the directory you'll see the same error.
If you want the root directory to be the project one there is certainly an option in the editor/IDE, just surf the web or look into settings (probably run configurations)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: The file could not be opened. It is mispelled, or not existing.

But most likely it is in a different directory.

Please use a full path for the file, then you can open it. Like

```
ifstream testFile("c:\\temp\\Test.txt");
```

Then, please do not use `is_open`.

Simply use

```
 if (testFile)
```

The `!` operator for `ifstream` is overwritten, so this will work.

Comment: You shouldn't mention "how easy" the question is. It is just noise making it harder for people to concentrate on the solution

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But As I intend to extend this program for Linux, I decided to keep the Test.txt file in the directory where the exe is kept. Also when it is fully functional , I will pass the fileName as cmd argument of the main function. So I can not give the full path as it may vary in the future.

Answer (score 0):

thanks all and I manage to get it working with the platform independent method. Please see the code below.

```
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>
#include <errno.h>
#include <filesystem>
using namespace std;

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    fs::path Path = fs::current_path() / argv[1];

    ifstream testFile(Path.c_str());

    string line;
    string str;
    if (testFile.is_open())
    {

        for (std::string line; std::getline(testFile, line);)
        {
            str += line;
        }
    }

    std::cout << str << endl;
}
```